# Range index over various date format

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I have various documents, each include different date/time format in header element. What will be the shortest step to achieve facet search based 9!'n range index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A true MarkLogic facet requires a range index, which means you'll have to convert all date/times to the official xs:dateTime format. I'd recommend this approach, nothing beats good and clean data.

If touching data is really no option, you could play around with TDE's to generate triples or sql views with normalized values. It won't integrate as well with ordinary search in MarkLogic though..

HTH!